# Is it possible to apply a “twist & squeeze” transformation to a whole HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question has been flagged as off-topic (apparently because it is to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource**), but I fail to see why. It is certainly not about recommending a tool or anything like that. I would just like to know if something is possible to do, and if it is: how.

Let's say we have some ordinary HTML page, and want to apply some graphical effect to it, just for a while, then return to the previous form as if nothing has happened.

An effect I have in mind is something like that:

[image: Floating page]

Are there any jQuery plugins (because it seems there is a jQuery plugin for *everything*) that can do that? Is it even doable, with HTML5 or CSS3 (I don't care much about legacy browsers support)?

The only thing I could come up with was to replace the page with some image, and then apply the transformation to that image, but that doesn't seem like a very good solution, because it would not be possible for the image to look exactly like what a user sees (since the page content is usually dynamic).

Okay, so CSS3 has this `transform` thing, but for what I can see it provides only relatively simple transformations. What about my case of twisting and squeezing?

Comment: Your question was itself funny !

Comment: yeah i too feel :) @shadow

Comment: I dont know how to accomplish something like that, but i have a example here for page transition.http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3PageTransitions/#home

Comment: We only need one more vote to re-open this.

Comment: Well you did ask if there was a jQuery plugin available... my guess is people were voting to close based on that. Anyway, reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: You can write CSS3 animation for `<html>` or `<body>`.

http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-full-page-animations-using-css/

Comment: For what I can see this CSS3 `transform` provides only relatively simple transformations. What about my case of twisting and squeezing?